# Implementing JavaFX shapes in different methods each

Tags: java, javafx

I have this working JavaFX code, that is used to draw four different shapes in a root frame. I would like each shape to have its own method that implements it, that is for instance if it is a circle, something like `public void circle(){//statements}` but I don't know how to do it. Please help me. Thank you.

```
package shapes;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author mach
 */
public class Shapes extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        Group root = new Group();
        //Draw a line
        Line line= new Line();
        line.setStartX(150);
        line.setStartY(20);
        line.setEndX(270);
        line.setEndY(20);
        line.setStroke(Color.RED);

        //Draw a circle radius (x,y,radius)
        Circle circle = new Circle(70, 110, 30);
        circle.setStroke(Color.RED);
        circle.setFill(Color.AQUA);

        //draw a Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(200, 90, 70,50);
        rect.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        rect.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        //Draw a triange
        Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
         triangle.getPoints().addAll(50.0, 0.0,  50.0, 50.0,100.0, 50.0);


        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
        //add all the created objects to canvas
        root.getChildren().addAll(line, circle, rect, triangle);

        primaryStage.setTitle("PART 1!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you saying you want a method that returns a new circle that you can add or a method that actually adds the circle to the screen. Also do you want just one single default type or parameters to change the specifics with

Comment: This is a quite vague question

Comment: I'm sorry about that.  Each shape should have its own method that draws it, but all the shapes are added to the screen using one method.

Comment: Here is a Java tutorial which explains how methods can be written and other related information: [Defining Methods in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 public Circle getCircle(){
        Circle circle = new Circle(70, 110, 30);
        circle.setStroke(Color.RED);
        circle.setFill(Color.AQUA);
        return circle;
}
```

Without knowing what you are working one, i only want to add that I generally would not know a good reason for using a method without any parameters here, and would advise against it.

Comment: @milk
This is nice. Thank you.  the last question is, 
how do I call this method to show the Circle object?

Comment: @TimothyMach if this answered your original question, mark it as the correct answer. If you have another question, start a new thread.

Comment: its part of the question. just knowing how to call the display the circle using this method is the only remain this.

Comment: You would use  `Circle circle = getCircle(); `
Alternativley you could do somethign like
 `root.getChildren().addAll(line, getCircle(), rect, triangle); `

Comment: @TimothyMach As it looks like my code answered your question it would be nice to mark it as correct answer - thanks.

Comment: @mik. okay. i have

Answer (score 0):

**This is an extension of the answer above.** 
After some research, I found out how to add the shapes to the root frame. Inside the `public void start(Stage primaryStage)` method, create an object of the class Shape and use the object to call the methods for the shapes. Assign the objects to a variable and add them to the frame in my case (root).

```
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Shapes frame = new Shapes();

        Circle circle  = frame.getCircle();
        Rectangle rectangle= frame.getRectangle();


     root.getChildren().addAll(circle, rectangle);  
   }
    public Rectangle getRectangle(){
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(200, 90, 70,50);
        rect.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        rect.setFill(Color.BLUE);
     return rect;
  }
```